# Magento + Paypal Express Checkout on Sandbox Mode

Tags: magento, paypal-sandbox, magento-1.9, paypal

I'm trying to test Paypal Express Checkout with a sandbox seller account, and with sandbox mode enabled on the Magento Configuration.

The "checkout with paypal" button shows up on shopping cart but when I click it it redirects me to an URL like:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=
```

And shows the following error:

```
Your session has ended

This transaction has expired....
```

According to this post, for sandbox mode I should be being redirected to something like:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=
```

When I copied the token and used such URL it worked fine.

What can I do to get the sandbox URL to be used when in sandbox mode?

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled that could be conflicting?  I can't think of any reason that wouldn't use the sandbox if you do indeed have sandbox mode enabled.

Comment: The only 3rd-party extension I have installed is IWD's one page checkout, but the same wrong url is used even when I click the express checkout button on the shopping cart.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with IWD and Paypal. If you are using IWD One Page Checkout, go to

`System > Configuration > IWD EXTENSIONS > One Page Checkout > Paypal Express LightBox`

and set `Enable Paypal Express Lightbox` to `No`. That fixed it for me.